# Moving an image up in CSS

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

So, for the past hour I've being trying to move this image using the css property `position`. My problem is every time I move it using `top` or `bottom` it doesn't work correctly. Here's a screenshot of it [before](https://i.gyazo.com/b767875a2bf22ae36d221604d2e00e4e.png) using said properties and [after](https://i.gyazo.com/efea99d47fb1c8b344811488a72a4933.png). Below you can find my html & css. Lastly, this `position` has to be `absolute` or the image completely disappears.

HTML

```
<section class="row posts">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <header><h3>What others have to say...</h3></header>
        @foreach($posts as $post)
            <article class="post" data-postid="{{ $post->id }}">
                <p>{{ $post->body }}</p>
                <div class="info">
                    Posted by {{ $post->user->user_name }} on {{ $post->created_at }}
                </div>
                <div class="interaction">
                    <a href="#" class="like heart"></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|
                    <a href="#" class="like">Dislike</a>
                    @if(Auth::user() == $post->user)
                        |
                        <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a> |
                        <a href="{{ route('post.delete', ['post_id' => $post->id]) }}">Delete</a>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </article>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.heart{
    background: url('http://localhost:8079/uncaughterror/public/src/img/web_heart_animation.png');
    background-position: left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 50px; width: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    left: 12px;
    bottom: 5px; //This or 'top' is what causes my entire problem
    background-size:1450px;
}

.heart:hover {
    background-position: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding this :

```
.interaction {
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should put the `no-repeat` at the same line as the `background`

It just work for me,i don't know why

https://jsfiddle.net/moongod101/2wh6b9rq/